# Paramiko usage : How to wait till the previous command is execute

Tags: python

I am writing a code to execute multiple commands and write it on to a file but facing issue that  it does not wait till the command is executed. Each command takes variable time to finish. I want this function to wait for one command to finish before it execute other. I have replaced the actual commands with ( commands x )

```
def user_debug_command_output ( user_ip, user_mac ):
  ssh_one = ssh.invoke_shell()
  print "Interactive SSH session established"
  print str(datetime.datetime.now())
  ssh_one.send("command 1 \n")
  ssh_one.send("commands 2\n" %user_ip)
  time.sleep(.1)
  ssh_one.send("commands 3 %s \n" %user_mac)
  time.sleep(.1)
  ssh_one.send("command 4\n")
  time.sleep(5)
  while not ssh_one.recv_ready():
   time.sleep(5)
  output_user = ssh_one.recv(-1)
  print output_user
  #time.sleep(5)
  fo = open ("user_debug_output.txt", 'w' )
  fo.write ( output_user.strip())
  fo.close()
```

Comment: Try `ssh.recv_exit_status()`   http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_exit_status

Comment: Hi Shiva
thank you for getting back to me
i have been printing the recv_exit_status()
it only returns "False"